# Is there any significance of RHP zeroes on a system's open loop behavior?

Tags: power-supply, control-system, boost, stability, frequency-response

In a closed loop boost converter, RHP zeroes will cause a phenomenon called ‘non-minimum phase’, which will make the closed loop system go in the opposite direction first when an external excitation has been applied.

Just to be clear, Is RHP zeroes only an issue only for closed loop behavior? (e.g.: I don't find any issues with an open-loop boost converter)

Comment: The way I like to look at this is that an RHP means a scale factor that is greater than 1. Without feedback, it's just a scale factor that is greater than 1. But with feedback, it's a outward-going spiral that just increases as the angle rotates. So I'd say that it is closed loop cases where this is a problem. (Though I'm sure there are cases where scaling by more than 1, just one time, also isn't good.)

Comment: Perhaps it's better to see *"outward-going spiral that just increases as the angle rotates"* more as *"ever-expanding helical coil in 3D space along the positive-going time axis."* It's just that \$e^{\left(\sigma+j\omega\right)t}\$ becomes \$e^{\sigma t}e^{j\omega t}\$. \$e^{j\omega t}\$ is just going to spin around circularly counter-clockwise, as \$t\to\infty\$. Who cares? But \$e^{\sigma t}\$ here is the real problem, as \$t\to\infty\$, when \$\sigma>0\$. Stuff gets out of hand then.

Answer (score 0):

Well, what are you doing with the open-loop system?  Normally we're concerned about these things in context of a closed-loop system, because they affect stability.  They will also affect the step response, settling time, etc.; some of which is contingent on the first assumption (stability, necessitating a compensator time constant below the plant's), but some which is also an intrinsic property of the plant being controlled, regardless of how we try to control it.

In closed-loop controls, to the extent we can't control them (such as the boost's fixed zero), it's just something we have to deal with, I think.

Whether zeroes can/should be used intentionally, in the design of a plant -- to whatever extent such characteristics can be designed in a given application -- I'm not sure offhand.

There are certainly cases of *open-loop* systems where zeroes are relevant, and intentional.

A low-pass filter with zeroes above the cutoff frequency, exhibits a shallower stop band, with, well, literal zero crossings.  That is, a 2nd-order filter for example has 40dB/decade attenuation for f ≫ f<sub>c</sub>, but with a zero, it will only have this attenuation from f<sub>c</sub> to f<sub>z</sub>, above which the attenuation flattens out, to 20dB/dec (single real zero) or 0 (two zeroes).  This seems undesirable, but it can be used to achieve a sharper transition band, when zeroes are placed near (above) f<sub>c</sub>.  The standard type is the Cauer/Elliptical filter, where both passband and stopband are specified as within a nominal range (filter ripple).  Put another way, it's the closest rational approximation* to a brick-wall filter, where the "brick wall" is literally some height above the ground; and as a rational approximation, it can be closer than a plain polynomial fit (all-pole filter).

*Lumped-element (RLC) filters have transfer functions expressed as ratios of polynomials, i.e., rational functions.

Zeroes are also used for phase shifting, such as phase/time delay equalization, which can be done independently of frequency response.  There's probably not much application for this anymore, with delays being trivial in DSP systems, and any response being completely tunable by mere choice of coefficients; but they were critical in the past, when analog systems dominated: ranging from early telephone applications (Zobel, among many other well-honored engineers, famously worked at Bell Labs and first solved filter design problems such as these) to radio communications, test equipment, and so on.

Historical diversion:

1960s era Tektronix oscilloscopes are a favorite example for many people.  They used low-pass and all-pass networks to extend the bandwidth of late-generation vacuum tubes, and early-generation semiconductors, as far as they possibly could; an [85MHz continuous analog bandwidth](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/585) was their crowning achievement using conventional components of the time.  These used peaking coils to partially cancel capacitance of single amplifying devices, or distributed amplifiers to cancel capacitance of arrays of them.  Distributed amplifiers and delay lines are applications of all-pass networks.  (Delays were necessary to compensate for amplifier vs. trigger logic delay; so that, when the electron beam begins its sweep, the signal arriving at the deflection plates includes the edge that it was actually triggered on.)  Transmission lines and hybrid structures were also in common use for delay lines.  Compare the meticulous lumped-element delay line from the [Tek 535A](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Delay_line#/media/File:Tek_535a_delay_line_2.jpg), to a helical one from the [Tek 585A](https://w140.com/tekwiki/wiki/Delay_line#/media/File:585a_delay1.jpg).

This answer unfortunately says a lot more about what your question *isn't* asking about, than what it is; but perhaps contrasting open-loop applications will be illuminating.

Comment: Those old scopes were really marvels of engineering.  They needed lots of trimming and factory calibration, but what they achieved with the available components was amazing.  If anyone ever has a chance to open one up and look at the internals and wiring, you should definitely study it.